# Load MySQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, load

I have MySQL server installed and I have created a test database named "test" and done a simple login example, with the ID, username, password and email. According to W3Schools, I have modified the code they provide:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password, email FROM user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["password"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I've searched the directory of the database and I see in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data a folder named "test" that contains 3 files, a .opt file, a .frm and a .ibd.

My question is, **where should I put the html file** in order to load this database data? Or should I change something from my code? Thanks!

Comment: HTML files always go in the web server root.

Comment: I've placed the html in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6. If I open the html with the web browser it does not load the file. How should I open it or what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running a webserver?

Comment: I have configured the Apache server in localhost and the MySQL server I think it is by default at 3036 port if that's what you are asking

Comment: Look in your Apache folder - there should be a www/ or htdocs/ or something that is the root web server folder. All your HTML shoulld go there until you learn how to modify directives.

Comment: Yes indeed. In the htdocs folder I have an index.html file and the html file that I've written in my post to load the data. What I do not know is what content from the database should I place in this folder (I have the .opt,.frm and .ibd files but I do not know what they do or if they are needed) and where should I place it.

Comment: I mean, in the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data there is a folder named "test" (my database) containing the 3 files mentioned. In the htdocs folder from apache I have the html that I have placed here in the post. What I do not know is what files and where should I place them to make it work. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you try to navigate to localhost in your browser?

Comment: Yes! It shows "It works!" As a default text. If I type localhost/bbddloader.html (the html file) it shows a table but not with the MySQL data from the database.

Comment: it needs to be a `.php` extension, there's the problem