# MySQLi database files

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to do [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo_table) from W3Schools:, but I can't test it as I do not know how to place the files in the proper location.

What I have:

- **3 Files** in the folder (being "myDB" the name of the DB) C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\myDB , which are: **db.opt**, **myGuests.frm** and **myGuests.ibd** and a SQL Dump named **myDB.sql**.
- The **html file** copied from the link I've given from W3Schools.

Which should be the **folder/file structuring** in order to make the html work by linking to the proper file(s)? I have installed Apache in the default port if this information is relevant (therefore I have the htdocs folder if needed).

Comment: why did you repost from http://stackoverflow.com/q/31082205/ ? don't you know that PHP/SQL doesn't run unless it's a `.php` extension or that you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set The file in Apache root folder.
you can instal Wamp Server or MAMP server

Go to https://localhost/phpmyadmin
then to import your DB

after that set the file in the www/htdocs folder

http://localhost/filename.php to test the output

Comment: xampp is the best ;)

Comment: I have installed it, and then when I open phpmyadmin I see my database at the left side. Then, I have created a htdocs folder inside the www folder and inside put the php file. Then I've tried to load it from firefox but it does not show the database data :/ any idea where it went wrong?